# What activity is there in Computer Go tournaments?

Tags: go, tournament, computer-ai

At the moment, the [17th TCEC superfinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_Chess_Engine_Championship) is running, [Stockfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stockfish_(chess)) vs. [Leela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leela_Chess_Zero). It is considered the unofficial world championship of computer chess, and games are frequently publicly commentated by professional chess players. TCEC runs tournaments continuously, 2-4 of them every year.

Given the advance of [Go programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Go), I wonder whether there are well-organized computer Go tournaments. I found the [Computer Go UEC Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Go_UEC_Cup), but Wikipedia says it took place annually from 2007-2017 and has stopped; also, its website has not been updated for several years. There is slightly confusing further information about a follow-up tournament in 2019, which points to Japanese websites.

Hence my questions:

> 1) Where can one get information in English about the UEC Cup? Do most state-of-the-art programs participate?
>
> 2) Are there other computer Go tournaments?

Comment: I am surprised that this has been voted both down and to close (2/5) with no comments whatsoever. While I have the impression the questioner could have found out more themself, I do not know why it should be so poor or inappropriate.

Comment: @PJTraill To be fair a what happens a lot on stack exchange in general is when someone posts what they think wrong with a post people tend to take it personal, assume things and attack the person who posted

Answer (score 4):

The  **[Computer Go Server](http://www.yss-aya.com/cgos/)**<sup>1</sup> is currently a very active test bed for bots. The [*Computer Go*](https://senseis.xmp.net/?ComputerGo) page at [Sensei’s Library](https://senseis.xmp.net/) refers, under ***Competitions***, to various competitions including the Computer Go Server, with [its own page](https://senseis.xmp.net/?ComputerGoServer) at Sensei’s Library, which gives the URL<sup>1</sup>. On that site, you will find daily updated tables of bots for [9×9](http://www.yss-aya.com/cgos/9x9/standings.html), [13×13](http://www.yss-aya.com/cgos/13x13/standings.html) and [19×19](http://www.yss-aya.com/cgos/19x19/standings.html), These refer to the Bayes ELO ratings pages (on the same site) where for example [the 19×19 page](http://www.yss-aya.com/cgos/9x9/bayes.html) as I write (2020-04-19 22:17) shows 1064 programmes ranging in strength from [DunceBot](http://www.yss-aya.com/cgos/9x9/cross/DunceBot.html) at 538 to [KG30b11_406_2x2060](http://www.yss-aya.com/cgos/9x9/cross/KG30b11_406_2x2060.html) at 3387. The non-Bayes page shows the date+time of the most recent game by each bot, showing that a game was played some two hours ago.

The page http://www.computer-go.info/events/index.html, though was described at Sensei’s Library as showing “all competitions” in fact covers the dates 1920–2017<sup>2</sup>.

I know no more than you of what has become of the [UEC Cup](https://senseis.xmp.net/?UECCup). Surprisingly, none of the [AlphaGo](https://senseis.xmp.net/?AlphaGo) variants appear although one convincingly defeated a top professional, [Lee Sedol](https://senseis.xmp.net/?LeeSedol), in 2016; more recent bots such as [LeelaZero](https://github.com/leela-zero/leela-zero) (released 2017-10-25) and [KataGo](https://github.com/lightvector/KataGo) (released 2019) appeared after the UEC Cup apparently stopped.

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>The current URL is http://www.yss-aya.com/cgos/ . Sensei’s also gave the URL http://cgos.boardspace.net/, but this appears not to work, which I have noted in Sensei’s.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>I have updated Sensei’s accordingly.</sub>

Comment: I'd guess none of the commercial vendors would like to compete against another. There is little to gain for either party, but much to lose. The only bots that were compared are those from OSS and (to a degree) academia.